# The concatenation of two independent normal vectors is multivariate normal.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I've already read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349059/the-probability-density-function-pdf-of-concatenation-of-two-gaussian-variable).

By the definition I have, 
$$\mathbf{z} = \begin{bmatrix}
z_1 & z_2 & \cdots & z_n 
\end{bmatrix}^{T}$$
is a multivariate standard normal vector if each $z_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ is iid.

Furthermore, $\mathbf{Az+b} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{T})$ (assuming that $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{b}$ are obviously conformable) is multivariate normal.

Suppose that I have two vectors $\mathbf{a} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_1, \mathbf{V}_1)$ and $\mathbf{b} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_2, \mathbf{V}_2)$ which are both $n$-dimensional and independent. How do I show that
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{a} \\
\mathbf{b}
\end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
 \boldsymbol{\mu}_1\\
\boldsymbol{\mu}_2 
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{V}_1 & \mathbf{0}_{n \times n} \\
\mathbf{0}_{n \times n} & \mathbf{V}_2
\end{bmatrix} \right)\text{?}$$

The mean vector and variance-covariance matrix are easy to derive, but I am stuck as to how to show *joint* normality.

Comment: Can you represent $[a \quad b]'$ as $Az+c$ where $z$ is a vector of iid $N(0,1)$?

Comment: @d.k.o. That's where my difficulty is. Can we say that $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ consist of different standard multivariate normal vectors because of their independence? I'm not sure.

Comment: Take $z=[V_1^{-1/2}(a-\mu_1) \quad V_2^{-1/2}(b-\mu_2)]'$ - a vector of independent $N(0,1)$.